# What's the best way to run a script without copying/moving files?

Tags: bash

I have to run scripts inside a container, and I want to avoid copying files into it. To work around this I currently use:

```
bash <<- 'EOF'
$(cat $scriptfile)
EOF
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: You could use `< $scriptfile` to simplify. You don't need the heredoc.

Comment: @jordanm is there a way to run multiple scripts in the same shell that way(so it's roughly equivalent to $(cat $script0)\n$(cat $script1))?

Comment: `$(cat script1 script2 script3)`

Comment: For the non-herdoc method `< <(cat script1 script2 script3)`

Answer (score 1):

Please specify in question, when you need to run a script in a container.

#### 1. At image build time (DOCKERFILE).

1. Use Bash [here document](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/) in DOCKERFILE

#### 2. At container start up.

1. Create a volume to the container (shared directory with host).
2. Call mounted script from `docker run` command.

#### 3. At scheduled time the container is up

1. Create a volume to the container (shared directory with host).
2. Create a `cron` job to run your script from mounted volume.

#### 4. On demand when the container is up

1. Run your script as argument to `ssh` command.

For example:

```
ssh -q containerAddress  <<< '
date +%F:%T   # line 1: time stamp
hostname -f     # line 2: hostname 
id              # line 3: user id
ip a | grep "inet " # line 4: assigned ip4 adresses
'
```

Another example:

```
ssh -q containerAddress  bash -c "$(cat <your-scirpt>)"
```